# Fiware - Wilma PEP Proxy does not validate SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, fiware, fiware-wilma

I have a scenario in which I want Wilma PEP Proxy redirecting to a server via HTTPS. This is working now, but the server certificate (self-signed) is not being validated.

In the config.js file, the only configuration about this is the following:

```
config.app_ssl = true; //true because I have Nginx doing HTTPS to HTTP for Orion
```

The HTTPS flow is working, but the Nginx certificate is not validated at Wilma.

Some suggestion to deal with this? Maybe this function can be added to Wilma and we will have some more parameters to configure at config.js file.

Comment: Hi, what issue are you getting in PEP?

Please, be sure you have correctly configured the port where your application is listening in https

Comment: Hi, @ÁlvaroAlonso . I have nginx working as a reverse proxy for Orion (https to http). So, the requests go to pep, using https, and after authentication/authorization process, they are sent to orion also using https from pep to nginx. As the nginx is listening to port 80, I left the application port configured with `config.app_port = '';` . It is empty. But there is no setup parameter to specify to pep which certificate it should validate.

Comment: We will check it. Probably it doesn't work with self signed certificates. Thanks for the report. You can of course try to find a solution and contribute it to the project

Comment: I will think about it, @Álvaro . For now, I did a change in Wilma in a way it can attest Intel SGX processors, improving the access control.